# spam HTTP Request triggered from the web page

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

In my web application, I can see spam HTTP requests initiated on the web URL. I have attached the chrome network screen which shows that several HTTP requests are initiated as ".wasm" files. Please suggest How to prevent it? Is it because of npm modules? a web application is built on the expo and react-native. I can see spam in my localhost also. I can see several npm packages with high severity. Is it because of that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The WASM requests are directed at `hostingcloud.racing`.

According to my Anti-Virus, this site is blocked due to a trojan.

Scan your system with an Anti-Virus solution first. Do not rely on Microsoft Defender alone.

( https://www.malwarebytes.com/ offers a free trial. )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I look up the website url and found this reddit post: [ISP CVE](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/9hnbcf/strange_javascript_injection_from_isp/)

Looks like your ISP has been compromised by [CVE-2018-14847](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-14847)

You should try `npm audit --force` to see if this is not packages problems.